# How can I remove null and ctrl+m characters from a CSV file?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed, tr

I have a CSV file that starts with NULL bytes that come from Hive Beeline CLI query output. The file starts with many lines that have `^Mnull^Mnull` in the first lines:

```
^Mnull                                                   ^Mnull^Mnull                                                   ^Mnull^Mnull                                                   ^Mnull^Mnull                                                   ^Mnull^Mnull                                                   ^Mnull^Mnull                                                   ^Mnull^Mnull                                                   ^Mnull^Mnull                                                   ^Mnull^Mnull                                                   ^Mnull^Mnull                                                   ^Mnull^Mnull                                                   ^Mnull^Mnull                                                   ^Mnull^Mnull                                                   ^Mnull^Mnull                                                   ^Mnull^Mnull                                                   ^Mnullid,date,num_val_1,units,orders,num_val,type,flag,double_val
"AAAAA",2020,33.0,0,0,599.0,"String",0,49.0
```

I tried `tr -d '\0' < file_with_null_bytes`, but that doesn't remove the `^Mnull`'s. I want to remove the `^Mnull`'s and spaces until the header from CSV file.

Comment: `less` would usually represent null bytes as `^@` - I suspect what you actually have is carriage returns `^M` followed by the literal string `null`. Try `sed 's/\rnull//g` or perhaps `sed '/\rnull/d'`

Comment: sed 's/\rnull//g' has removed the ^Mnull but left me a lot of spaces

Comment: Yeah that's why I suggested the second option (which will delete whole *lines* that contain `^Mnull`)

Comment: my header is also include ^Mnull so it is problem (it removed my header as well)

Comment: Then please [edit] your question to show **exactly** what you want to remove - and what you want to replace it with